# How do you find out when a Java class was introduced to the Standard Java API?

Tags: java, api

How do you find out when a Java class was introduced to the Standard Java API?

Answer (score 2):

The javadoc will have a **Since** tagline, for instance on `java.util.List`:

> **Since**
>
> 1.2

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Therefore it has been around since Java 1.2 (Java J2SE 1.2)